# Manual Interpretation of SARIMA Coefficients (Possible Without Pie/Psi Weights?)

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive, seasonality, statsmodels

I am struggling to render the output of a SARIMA model into an intelligible linear expression that I can use to make projections manually. I encountered [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157748/seasonal-arima-forecast-equation) on CrossValidated, but I am not well-versed in psi/pie weights, and am hoping to avoid the need to calculate them. [This sample code](https://machinelearningmastery.com/make-manual-predictions-arima-models-python/) makes me think that I can apply the coefficient estimates for the AR terms to the lagged values of the time series, and apply the coefficient estimates for the MA terms to the error terms. I have attempted to do this manually, but have not yet been able to match the output of [StatsModels predict()](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults) function. The model specification is SARIMAX(2, 1, 1)x(2, 0, [1, 2], 24), and the coefficient estimates I've estimated are as follows:
 [image]

 The linear expression that I've tried thus far is below:
[image]

Conceptually, I'm applying the AR coefficient to the appropriate time step, and then in the event that there is a MA term, I'm scaling the error term from the AR model by the MA coefficient estimate for that time. 
 It's clear to me that something is off with my understanding regarding how these coefficient estimates are applied. Can anyone please clarify in simple terms? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: In your evaluation of the error term, taking a difference between consecutive ys is a mistake. The error term is defined differently.

Comment: Thank you Richard. Can you shed insight on the correct specification? Can I simply fetch this value from the model's stored residuals'?

Comment: If you have the stored residuals, use them.

Comment: Thank you Richard. I think my confusion then stems from the fact that I don't have line-of-sight into how these residuals were created. Stepping back - if a MA model is of the form X_t = mu + e_t + theta_1 (e_t-1) ... theta_q (e_t-q) where the theta terms are the parameters of the model and e_t - e_q are white noise error terms, I would love to be able to recover the expression that the non-linear fitting procedure aligned on for specifying these error terms. However, this may not be possible (at least in statsmodels). I'm going to mark this as 'answered' but would love your thoughts here.

Comment: Estimation of ARIMA models is a really complicated matter, at least from my point of view. Things like OLS will not work. I would post a brief answer but hate to type on my phone, and I do not have access to my laptop now.

Comment: Agreed - the fact that most packages use non-linear fitting suggests that a simple linear expression may not be sufficient to encapsulate the logic. I would love to know which software packages preserve this logic (in some form or another) following estimation, but that is not so much a statistics question as a programming one :)

Comment: I think none use (versions of) linear fitting as it is suboptimal for ARIMA models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual forecasting is possible using the original coefficient estimates coupled with the stored residuals (no hard requirement to convert to psi-weights or pi-weights). The question of how the residuals were generated is a natural follow-up, but is off topic relative to the initial question. Thank you Richard Hardy for all your help.